# Database context being used in Controllers in MVC projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Specific question - how can I bounce a `DbContext` created in `Startup` in an ASP.Net CORE web app to a `Data Access Layer` without it passing through a controller first?

Currently the pattern goes:

```
request starts ---> dbcontext created ---> dbcontext passed to controller ---> pass to DAL --> return items
```

But I really just want

```
request starts ---> controller instanced ---> controller calls dal ---> dbcontext created -- return items
```

The problem I'm having is getting the configuration from the appsettings into the dal.

---

**Background:**

In old Framework projects I have a Data Access Layer which I instance and dispose of with a single line statement in a Controller, generally like so:

```
List<stuff> MyListOfStuff = new DAL().GetStuff();
Return View(MyListOfStuff)
```

Normally having mapped these lists / objects to ViewModels in the same line using chain syntax or whatever mapping methods needed.

The context is instanced during the DAL() creation and gets its parameters from the global.asax or web.config

I'm pretty sure I ended up with this habit because (I think) I read in a lot of places that business logic and data access logic shouldn't go in Controllers. Controllers should be as minimal as possible?

I'm now learning asp.net core where the context is configured at startup and instanced out of sight and passed to a controller by default, and the MSDN tutorial is showing we should just use that context right in the controller without using or passing it to another layer at all.

Are the tutorials just showing us a quick, minimal way of doing things in order to get started or is this actually best practice? I prefer instancing contexts in the DAL only and can't really see a benefit yet to the other way, and can't figure out how to pull my `appsettings.json` configured DbContexts in to any old DAL class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: The tutorial is showing you a best practice called Dependency Injection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The Old Framework way that you used works fine, but will make writing unit tests difficult. For simple apps using the dbcontext in the controller is okay, but most of the time you will want to move that logic to a Service or Repository layer which is just a new version of the DAL layer you are used to. (https://medium.com/net-core/repository-pattern-implementation-in-asp-net-core-21e01c6664d7)

Comment: If you have a specific data access layer, then your controller should get an instance of that, and the data access layer should depend on the context via its constructor. Seems like you're not understanding the point of Depedency Injection. You should probably watch [Deep Dive into Dependency Injection and Writing Decoupled Quality Code and Testable Software](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412). Any time you're creating an instance of a class (besides dumb data classes that contain no logic), you're probably violating IoC principles.

Comment: Once I started thinking about it in a DI context and how I can pass alternative contexts to my Unit Tests I realised the benefits. Tutorials like that always have so many points in it that I get overwhelmed, and it doesn't even talk about DI til after halfway down, I just didn't realise. Thanks @schwechel for highlighting that topic!